# How to target ads for location in admon

Tags: android, admob

I using Admob banners, All the banner in app are defined in XML.

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="................."
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

In the manifest permissions are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Does Admob has enough info to target ads for location. How can I enable use of coarse location. I see that ads are country specific. Am I loosing on revenue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is on the [Admob Google docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate), pressing on the Android tab.

- Targeting

  Location and demographic targeting information may also be specified. Out of respect for user privacy, Google asks that you only specify location and demographic data if that information is already used by your app.

  `AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
  request.setGender(AdRequest.Gender.FEMALE);
  request.setLocation(location);
  request.setBirthday("19850101");`

where the user's location is obtained by a [suitable method](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).